# Mutt: gmail archive

Tags: mutt

I want to recreate the gmail archiving method. I sync (using offlineimap) my inbox and my all mail folders, and, by archiving, I want to keep the one in All Mail and delete the one in inbox. Also, when I read a new mail in inbox I would like to automatically mark as read the corresponding mail into all mail.

I tried using the macro `index, pager A s><return>y` (I have set All Mail folder to $mbox), but the problem is that I get duplicate mails in the All Mail folder. Also, if I try to just delete the mail from Inbox, the corresponding one from All Mail gets deleted too.

**Later edit:**

Doing some more research into this topic I found that the duplicate mail in the All Mail mailbox stays there for 2 syncs: one to send it to gmail, which recognizes that it's a duplicate and deletes it, and one to delete it locally. So it seems that my macro works, but I would like to overcome this annoying issue.

Comment: It may be difficult, as Gmail stores messages differently than it is implemented in IMAP. The messages are tagged with folder name on the Gmail server, but remote IMAP clients (like `offlineimap`) see the tags as directories...

Answer (score 4):

It's very annoying indeed because offlineimap keep downloading things twice, one for inbox and one for all mail. So I fingure out one trick: I don't sync All Mail at all! Instead I sync just Inbox and everything else.

I am very grateful to know a better way around.